# "Can only update a mounted or mounting component" warning comes up while using a setInterval

Tags: reactjs, react-native, setinterval

I am developing an App with React Native. I need to retrieve some data using fetch every 30 seconds. My code works fine and it retrieves the data correctly every 30 seconds. My problem is that as soon as I redirect to another screen, I get the following warning:

> Warning: Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually
>   means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a
>   no-op. Please check the code for the xxxxxxxxx component.

Here is my code:

```
dataGet() {

    listColumnFetch(this).then(result => {
      let ColumnData = result.list;
      let ColumnDataArray = Object.keys(ColumnData).map((key) => { return ColumnData[key] });
      console.log("serverDataArray:", this.ColumnDataArray);
      this.setState({
        ColumnData,
        ColumnDataArray,
        isLoading: false,
        CurrentData: new Date(),
      });
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.dataGet();
    this.interval = setInterval(() => this.dataGet(), 30000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }
```

Although I did `clearInterval` in `componentWillUnmount`, the App gives me that warning every 30 seconds in other pages. It seems that the timer didn't stop and it is in background. Can you help me to solve this problem?

UPDATE: 
Also here I try to redirect to another page. Here is the rest of my code:

```
 onPressNew() {

        this.props.navigation.navigate('RechargeElectricCar', {user: this.state.user, activeSection: 'NoChargeInProgress_2a'});

      }

    render() {
          if (this.state.isLoading) {
            return(
              <View>
                <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#79b729"/>
              </View>
            );
          }
            return (
                <View  style={styles.container} ref="park-progress-ref">
                    <View style={styles.titleContainer}>
                         <Text style={styles.itemBold}>{I18n.t('queste_ricariche')}</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={ styles.rowSep } />
                    <View style={ styles.listContainer } >
                            <FlatList
                            ItemSeparatorComponent={ () => <View style={ styles.rowSep } /> }
                            horizontal={false}
                            data={this.state.result}

                            renderItem={
                            ({item}) => (
                                    <View style={styles.containerrow}>
                                         <View style={styles.viewPark}>

                                            <Text style={styles.itemBold}> {I18n.t('Data_e_ora_inizio')}: <Text style={styles.itemNormal}>{item.start}</Text></Text>
                                            <Text style={styles.itemBold}> {I18n.t('Data_e_ora_termine')}: <Text style={styles.itemNormal}>{item.end}</Text></Text>
                                            <Text style={styles.itemBold}> {I18n.t('Energia')}: <Text style={styles.itemNormal}>{item.energy_delivered} KWh</Text></Text>
                                            <Text style={styles.itemBold}> {I18n.t('Colonna')}: <Text style={styles.itemNormal}>{item.column_id}</Text></Text>
                                            <Text style={styles.itemBold}> {I18n.t('Costo_della_ricarica')}: <Text style={styles.itemNormal}>€ {item.amount}</Text></Text>
                                            <Text style={styles.itemBold}> {I18n.t('Aggiornamento_del')}: <Text style={styles.itemNormal}>{this.currentTime()}</Text></Text>

                                         </View>

                                         <View style={styles.rowCenter}>
                                            <Button label={I18n.t('Via_questa_ricarica')} color={defStyleValues.RechargeElectricCar} onPress={ () => {console.log("MARCO log"); this.onPressTopUp(item.column_id)} } />
                                         </View>
                                    </View>
                                )
                            }
                            keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                            />
                        </View>
                        <View style={ styles.rowSep } />

                            <View style={ styles.buttonContainer } >
                                <FadeInView
                                  duration={2000}
                                  style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}>
                                      <ButtonIcon_White  onPress={ () => { this.onPressNew() }} label={I18n.t('Nuova_ricarica')} />
                                </FadeInView>
                            </View>
                </View>
            );

        }
```

Comment: Are you pushing another screen or pop the screen? Do a `console.log` on `componentWillUnmount` and see if it logs.

Comment: Where the redirection part?

Comment: What is in `clearInterval`?  What problem does it solve?

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I will update you in question in seconds.

Comment: @bennygenel:Thanks for your answer, that's strange! it did't show me the console log there. Which means it id't executed! Do you have any idea?

Comment: @jmargolisvt: it will stop the interval before the screen changes.

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN: Thanks,  I have added it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you navigate to a new screen, the new screen will be pushed on top of the previous screen. Because of this the previous screen will not be unmounted. This is why your interval is not clearing.

What you can do is to set a variable or a state value before doing a redirection and then checking the value before doing another `setState`.

Another thing to consider is to changing the value when you come back to previous screen. To handle that you can pass a function as a parameter to next screen and run it when the next screen's `componentWillUnmount` like below.

**Example**

```
onPressNew() {
  // set stop value before navigating
  this.setState({ stop: true }, () => { 
    this.props.navigation.navigate('RechargeElectricCar', {
      user: this.state.user, 
      activeSection: 'NoChargeInProgress_2a', 
      onBack: this.onBack  // Added this param for changing state to false
    });
  });
}

onBack = () => {
  this.setState({stop: false});
}

//....

dataGet() {
  // check stop value before fetching
  if(this.state.stop !== true) {
    listColumnFetch(this).then(result => {
      let ColumnData = result.list;
      let ColumnDataArray = Object.keys(ColumnData).map((key) => { return ColumnData[key] });
      console.log("serverDataArray:", this.ColumnDataArray);
      this.setState({
        ColumnData,
        ColumnDataArray,
        isLoading: false,
        CurrentData: new Date(),
      });
    });
  }
}
```

On next screen (*RechargeElectricCar* screen)

```
componentWillUnmount() {
  this.props.navigation.state.params.onBack()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your nice answer, so it means that componentWillUnmount() never executed, right?

Comment: @Reza It will execute if you do `this.props.navigation.goBack()`

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot, I voted up and mark it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with your setState setting state when your component has unmounted.

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.isMountedComp = true
}

dataGet() {

    listColumnFetch(this).then(result => {
      let ColumnData = result.list;
      let ColumnDataArray = Object.keys(ColumnData).map((key) => { return ColumnData[key] });
      console.log("serverDataArray:", this.ColumnDataArray);
if(this.isMountedComp) {
  this.setState({
        ColumnData,
        ColumnDataArray,
        isLoading: false,
        CurrentData: new Date(),
      });
    });

}      
}

componentWillUnMount() {
 clearInterval(this.interval);
 this.isMountedComp = false
}
```

This will remove the warning errors.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it still exist. Do you any more information?

Comment: Do you have any more setState any where your component?

Comment: Yes, I have. But this warning occurs whenever I added setinterval. I updated the question.

Comment: They are in the dataGet() function.